# How to create directory in Linux Partition

Tags: linux, debian, fdisk, proxmox

i have installed proxmox 6 on my 500 GB SSD Drive

on summary screen of my node its showing

```
 HD space(root) 8.67% (8.15 GiB of 93.99 GiB)
 SWAP usage 0.00% (0 B of 8.00 GiB
```

which mean there is still somewhere about 360 GB space free on drive.

so when i do `fdisk -l`

i get list of my partitions

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       34      2047      2014  1007K BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1050624 976773134 975722511 465.3G Linux LVM
```

so i wonder how can i access `/dev/sda3` partition and how can i make directory inside like it as i have installed virtualizor with proxmox so i need to add storage to virtualizor. because currently virtualizor is just detecting proxmox root as storage

```
/var/lib/vz     93.99 GB (size)   81.03 GB ( free )
```

so any idea how to make storage directory in /dev/sda3 so that i can add it to virtualizor i tried change directory to it but no success like

`cd /dev/sda3`
also mkdir failed
`mdir /dev/sda3/my_storage`

**update**

`df` command output

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                  16404492       0  16404492   0% /dev
tmpfs                  3285944   17192   3268752   1% /run
/dev/mapper/pve-root  98559220 9549988  83959684  11% /
tmpfs                 16429716   46800  16382916   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                 16429716       0  16429716   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/fuse                30720      16     30704   1% /etc/pve
tmpfs                  3285940       0   3285940   0% /run/user/0
```

`mount` ouput

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=16404492k,nr_inodes=4101123,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3285944k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/pve-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=20771)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
lxcfs on /var/lib/lxcfs type fuse.lxcfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/dev/fuse on /etc/pve type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3285940k,mode=700)
```

`lsblk` output

```
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0  1007K  0 part 
├─sda2               8:2    0   512M  0 part 
└─sda3               8:3    0 465.3G  0 part 
  ├─pve-swap       253:0    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root       253:1    0    96G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta 253:2    0   3.5G  0 lvm  
  │ └─pve-data     253:4    0 338.4G  0 lvm  
  └─pve-data_tdata 253:3    0 338.4G  0 lvm  
    └─pve-data     253:4    0 338.4G  0 lvm  
sdb                  8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
```

Comment: Your sda3 contains an LVM volume group. This means that most likely you need to use the Proxmox LVM storage backend, as described in the documentation: https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/chapter-pvesm.html#storage_lvm

Comment: could you please add to your question `df` and `mount` output ? that would help I'm not sure to understand what is your problem.

Comment: You do not use standard partition tools with LVM. see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm  If also encrypted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu or skip the encryption part of the commands.

Comment: @Kiwy i added outputs you requested.

Comment: I don't understand, the result of `mount` you should have `/dev/sda*` or `/dev/mapper/*` available somehow.... that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

Your drive is partitioned using the GPT partitioning scheme into 3 partitions, that take up the whole of the disk.

The third GPT partition is used as a LVM physical volume. LVM (Logical Volume Management) is another much more advanced partitioning scheme. It is much more than a partitioning scheme.

It's used to pool a number of (general physical) block devices such as disks or partition formatted as *Physical Volumes* (PV) into a *Volume Group* (VG). And then out of that *Volume Group*, can be created a number of *Logical Volumes* (LV) in a variety of ways (with redundancy, with thin provisioning, with snapshot support, etc).

In your case, there's one VG called `pve` that is made of just one `PV` (sdb3). As shown by `lsblk`, but you could also use `lvs` or `lvdisplay` to get more information, 3 LVs have been created in that VG:

- `swap`: a plain "linear" volume which is used for swap
- `root`: another plain "linear" volume formatted with an `ext4` file system, and mounted on `/`. That's the root file system where all your files and dirs are.
- `data`: That's a thin pool which is made of two volumes one for data, one for metadata. That in turn can be used to create thinly provisioned volume. That is volumes which appear of a given fixed size, but are only allocate as needed.

If we do the maths,

```
$ zcalc
1> 8 + 96 + 3.5 + 334.4
441.9
2> 465.3 - $1
23.4
```

There's about 23.4 GiB free in that VG. It's a good idea to leave some space free in a VG so you can use it to snapshot other volumes.

The `data` thin pool, in Proxmox VE will typically be used to store VM disk images as thin LVs. It should be mapped to a *lvm* type datastore in the configuration, and that should be where you want to store your VM disk images.

You could also create another thin LV in that thin pool (see `lvcreate` man page)  and format it with some Linux file systems such as `ext4` (see `mkfs.ext4` man page) and mount it to some directory (see `mount` page) to give you extra storage to store regular files and directories, or you could reduce the size of the thin pool and enlarge the `root` LV (and enlarge the file system in it after that) to give you more space in the root FS.

Answer (score -3):

You need to mount the drive first.

mount /dev/sdb /mnt

then make your directory

cd /mnt

mkdir my_storage